# Cachetools with multiprocessing

Tags: python

I have an application that currently spins up multiple Processes in `main.py`, and each of those processes call a class Object to start, solely to have that class available to the `run()` function.

This design has 2 big problems:

1. It's very non-DRY
2. Each process is instantiating the Object (which also equals an API hit to determine if the auth token needs to be refreshed)

Now I'm trying to minimize the API hits and figured I'd look into caching the Object and only have it hit the API 1/per hour.

My initial thought was to use `cachetools.TTLCache` and `Multiprocessing.Manager.Queue`, but I can't honestly tell if this is going to work.

Here is the gist of the project:

```
main.py
--------
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == "__main__":
  p1 = Process(target=process1.run)
  p2 = Process(target=process2.run)
  p3 = Process(target=process3.run)
  p4 = Process(target=process4.run)
  p1.start()
  p2.start()
  p3.start()
  p4.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
  p3.join()
  p4.join()
```

Each 'process' is its own module that does it's own thing, but they all have the same basic structure:

```
process1.py/process2.py/process3.py/process4.py
--------
import TClient as client

c = client.TClient()

def run():
  data = c.get_info_from_api()
  ....
```

Lastly, the object class itself:

```
client.py
------
class TClient():
  def __init__(self):
    self.client = self._make_client()

  def _make_client(self):
    '''
      Creates the client needed to perform actions via the API
    '''
    try:
      c = auth.client_from_token_file(token_path, api_key, enforce_enums=False)
    except FileNotFoundError:
      c = auth.client_from_manual_flow(api_key, redirect_uri, token_path, enforce_enums=False)
    return c
```

So, what I'm hoping to do, is consolidate (put into shared memory?) the `TClient()` object so that each process isn't calling it.  Instead, it's better managed through its own process which would resolve the non-DRY & the many API hits issues.

The reason that I am also looking into cachetools is because `client.TClient()` does have to be called every once and a while to ensure the auth token from the API is ok (or needs to be refreshed). With that I believe that I'd be making a new function and Process to cache the client:

```
new_process.py
----
from cachetools import cached, TTLCache

@cached(cache = TTLCache(maxsize=1, ttl=3600))
def checkClient():
  c = client.Create_Or_Refresh()
  return c
```

Is this possible with the libraries that I'm looking at?  If so, is there a working example out there to reference?  All the documentation that I've been reading through talks about passing things between processes, but the example code only has variables being passed to 1 process from main.py, not from 1 to many processes.

Thanks in advance!